# css id in custom html helper

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have my custom html helper and want to add css id tag there.
this is my custom html helper:

```
 public static class CustomHtmlHelpers
{
    public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src)
    {
        TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");
        tb.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(src));
        return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

and here's my code in razor view:

```
<div class="display-label">
   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Photo)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
   @Html.Image(@Model.Photo)
</div>
```

I have tried

```
@Html.Image(@Model.Photo, new { @id = "myId" })
```

but it doesn't works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static class CustomHtmlHelpers
{
    public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, 
        string src, 
        object htmlAttributes)
    {
        TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");
        tb.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(src));
        tb.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

and html

```
@Html.Image(@Model.Photo, new { @id = "myId" })
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try change your HTML helper to this:

```
public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, object htmlAttributes)
```

and add code:

```
tb.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
```

Link: 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs